# How to create table and field using db_schema.xml in magento 2

Tags: magento2, db-schema

I want to create table and fields using db_schema.xml rather than InstallSchema in custom module. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 8):

> Create file **db_schema.xml**

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/etc**

**db_schema.xml**

```
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="declarative_table">
        <column xsi:type="int" name="id_column" padding="10" unsigned="true" nullable="false" comment="Entity Id"/>
        <column xsi:type="int" name="severity" padding="10" unsigned="true" nullable="false" comment="Severity code"/>
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="title" nullable="false" length="255" comment="Title"/>
        <column xsi:type="timestamp" name="time_occurred"  comment="Time of event"/>
        <column xsi:type="mediumtext" name="desc" nullable="true" comment="Value"/>
        <constraint xsi:type="primary" referenceId="PRIMARY">
            <column name="id_column"/>
        </constraint>
   </table>
</schema>
```

> **Explanation**

```
<table>
```

**-> Engine:** SQL engine, this value must be InnoDB or memory.

**-> Resource:** The database shard on which to install the table. This value must be default, checkout, or sales

```
<Column>
```

**-> identity:**    Indicates whether a column is auto incremented.

**-> Type:** blob,blob (includes blob, mediumblob, longblob), boolean, date, datetime, int (includes smallint, bigint, tinyint), real (includes decimal, float, double, real), text (includes text, mediumtext, longtext), timestamp, varbinary, and varchar.

**-> Padding:** indicates the size of the integer column

**-> Length:** indicates the length of a column

**-> precision:** The number of allowed digits in a real data type.

**-> scale:** The number of digits after the decimal in a real data type.

```
<Constraints>
```

**-> Type:** primary, unique, or foreign

**-> Referrence_id:** a custom identifier that is used only for relation mapping in the scope of db_schema.xml files

> **For Remove**

**-> disabled:**    Disables or deletes the declared table, column, constraint, or index.

> **Run this Command after installing table**

```
 php bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist --module-name=Vendor_Module
```

> -> The **db_schema_whitelist.json** will be created in **app/code/VenodreName/ModuleName/etc**

> **Drop table**

```
-> First of all, you need to add disabled="true" attribute in your table node.
-> Remove all nodes in between table

<table name="declarative_table" disabled="true">

</table>

-> php bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist --module-name=Vendor_Module
-> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

**if padding error come please romove it**

> **Rename table when Mirgrate**

```
This is a DDL trigger that allows you to move data from an existing column to a newly created column. This trigger works only when a column is created

USE THIS-> onCreate=”migrateDataFromAnotherTable(old name)”

-> Please note that migrating data from another table and renaming columns at the same time is not supported.

    <table name="new_declarative_table" onCreate="migrateDataFromAnotherTable(declarative_table)">


-> php bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist --module-name=Vendor_Module
-> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

> **Add a column to table**

```
add simple  <column> into table


-> php bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist --module-name=Vendor_Module
-> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

> **Drop a column from a table**

```
Add simple attribute  disabled="true" to <column>

-> php bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist --module-name=Vendor_Module
-> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

> **Change the column type**

```
directly change <column>

-> php bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist --module-name=Vendor_Module
-> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

> **Add primary key into ondelete  CASEDELETE**

```
 <constraint xsi:type="foreign" referenceId="[REFERENCE ID NAME]" table="[Current table name]" column="[Current table column name]" referenceTable="[refernce table name]" referenceColumn="[Refernce column name]"  onDelete="CASCADE"/>

-> php bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist --module-name=Vendor_Module
-> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

> **Add simple Primary key**

```
<constraint xsi:type="primary" referenceId="PRIMARY">
        <column name="id_column"/>
</constraint>

-> php bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist --module-name=Vendor_Module
-> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

> **Remove Primary key or Constraint**

```
Simply add to disabled="true" to <constraint>

-> php bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist --module-name=Vendor_Module
-> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

***Note:  When you change in  db_schema.xml you must to run php bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist --module-name=Vendor_Module after php bin/magento setup:upgrade command, Otherwise change not reflect. we must update db_schema_whitelist.json.***

**NOTE: This is only working with Magento 2.3.X or greater version.**

Comment: Hey, I made a schema, then generated a whitelist in the module.The whitelist.json looked correct based on what my `db_schema.xml` said, but when I run `s:up` it does not add a table, does anyone else have the same issue? Magento Open Source 2.3.5

Comment: Please read above note here your db_schema_whitelist.json file is must be updated. without updating file no any changes are comes.

Comment: My issue was not with the table not updating - it was with the table not being visible in the db at all, even though I had generated the whitelist, anyways it was a silly error - if anyone on PHPStorm has this problem make sure to refresh your database manager!

Comment: *being generated

Comment: @Msquare This information I just found here because I am still search and trying to get assistance with my query here (I created the question yesterday since I am stuck): _my question is directly related to 'cached' old db_schema.xml content_.  May you please try to assist in my question here : [db_schema.xml generate-whitelist does not refresh changes](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/360898/db-schema-xml-setupdb-declarationgenerate-whitelist-constraints-index-changes).

Answer (score 1):

First, create a file as given below **path**:

***app\code\Vendor\Extension\etc\db_schema.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="custom_table_name" resource="default" engine="innodb" comment="Comment Here">
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="column_name" nullable="false" length="10" comment="column comment here"/>
        <constraint xsi:type="primary" referenceId="PRIMARY">
            <column name="column_name"/>
        </constraint>
    </table>
</schema>
```

After completing the steps of creating the file as per given in the above steps, you need to run the following command:

**php bin/magento setup:upgrade**

after Check in the **database table** will be created as per shown :

please check more detail check this [link](https://magecomp.com/blog/how-to-create-custom-table-via-xml-in-magento-2/).

NOTE: This is only working with Magento 2.3.X or greater version.