# php bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist

Tags: magento2.3, database

I had some issues when updating an module, I revived an error and after looking it up It was recomaneded to do php bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist.  AFter i did this I was able to run decompile.

However now I have issues where I can't seem to go back to a previous version of my database. I get this error now when I try to save changes:

{ Unable to save categories with ID 1. Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'main_table.url_key' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT `main_table`.`category_id`, `store`.`store_id` FROM `amasty_blog_categories` AS `main_table` LEFT JOIN `amasty_blog_categories_store` AS `store` ON main_table.category_id = store.category_id WHERE (main_table.url_key = :url_key) AND (store.category_id != :category_id) AND (store.store_id IN (:store_id))}

Anyone know why this happening?

Comment: try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/309514/how-to-create-table-and-field-using-db-schema-xml-in-magento-2/309554#309554

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the error message, the problem comes from one of the Amasty extensions. You can uninstall it or disable it then retry the commands you implemented earlier.