# What is declarative schema in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

What is in short words declarative schema? Thanks for any help)

Comment: Navigate to the DevDocs https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/components/declarative-schema/

Comment: Try this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/309554/82670

Answer (score 2):

Its a different method of defining database schema.

From the docs:

> The new declarative schema approach allows developers to declare the
> final desired state of the database and has the system adjust to it
> automatically, without performing redundant operations. Developers are
> no longer forced to write scripts for each new version. In addition,
> this approach allows data be deleted when a module is uninstalled.

Source: https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/components/declarative-schema/

Example

**Previous method**

- Version 1: add column A to table
- Version 2: add columns B add C table
- Version 3: remove column B from table

Net result after version 3 is a table with columns A and C

**Declarative schema method**

You just define the net result you want.

- Version 1: table with column A
- Version 2: table with column A and B
- Version 3: table with Column A and C

Net result after version 3 is a table with columns A and C

Answer (score 1):

Basically, instead of using an InstallSchema class that extends Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface, you can use xml to define your database schema.

**Previous Method:**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();
        
        $table = $installer->getConnection()->newTable($installer->getTable('some_table_name'))
                ->addColumn('example_id',       \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER, 10,  ['unsigned' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true,'auto_increment' => true], 'example id')
                ->addColumn('order_id',                 \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER, 10,  ['nullable' => false],  'order id');
                
        $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
    }
}
```

**New Method:**
Vendor/Module/etc/db_schema.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    
    <table comment="some_table_name Table" engine="innodb" name="some_table_name" resource="default">
        
        <column comment="Example Id" identity="true" name="example_id" nullable="false" padding="6" unsigned="true" xsi:type="smallint"/>
        <constraint referenceId="PRIMARY" xsi:type="primary">
            <column name="example_id"/>
        </constraint>
        
        <column name="order_id" nullable="false" xsi:type="int" comment="order id"/>
        
    </table>
</schema>
```